# Javascript innerhtml issues=

Tags: javascript, html

```
function storename() {
  playereen = document.getElementById('p1').value;
  playertwee = document.getElementById('p2').value;
  console.log(playereen);
  console.log(playertwee);
  document.getElementById("outputa").innerHTML = playereen;
}
```

I am trying to store an input from a form into a variable and then make it appear on the screen. It had this error:  Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

html

```
<div class="scoreboard-wrapper">
  <h1 class="scoreboard-titel">Scoreboard</h1>
  <p>Player 1 - </p><div id="outputa"></div>
  <p>Player 2 - </p><div id="outputb"></div>
  <button onclick="start()" id="startbtn">Start</button>
</div>
```

form:

```
`<form id="form1">
        <p id="logintekst">Enter your names!</p>
        <input id="p1" class="form" type="text" placeholder="Player 1">
        <input id="p2" class="form" type="text" placeholder="Player 2">
        <a onclick="storename()" href="memory.html"><div onclick="storename()" id="submit-btn">Submit</div></a>
    </form>
```

`

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you spelled `output` wrong, but if that's not the case then an element with the id `outputa` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Please post the entire HTML. It looks the "outputa" is not defined

Comment: I did spell it correctly it is exactly the same

Comment: Maybe problem is not with `outputa`, but the fact that there is no `#p1` and `#p2` elements?

Comment: Your code works [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/3x86d5ow/) assuming that your other HTML is valid.

Comment: I added the form that i use

Comment: When you click the link in the form, you tell it to navigate to "memory.html". What is that about? Do you want to show a result, or do you want to navigate to memory.html?

Comment: With the form included, it still [works](http://jsfiddle.net/3x86d5ow/1/). There is something you left out. There is no reason for the actual error you mention.

Comment: Where do you have your script included? Inline, at the top, at the bottom? It would be best to create a runnable snippet that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/uuKJvGL15ADpB1Iu1k3Y?p=preview) plunker. It shows you how to do what you want. 
Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
       <p id="logintekst">Enter your names!</p>
       <input id="p1" class="form" type="text" placeholder="Player 1">
       <input id="p2" class="form" type="text" placeholder="Player 2">
        <a onclick="this.href='memory.html? 
        playereen='+document.getElementById('p1').value" 
         href=''>Submit</a>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

memory.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
           function getname() {
               var url = new URL(window.location.href);
               var playereen= url.searchParams.get("playereen");
               document.getElementById("outputa").innerHTML = 
               playereen;
           }

       </script>
       <title>Page Title</title>

    </head>
    <body onload="getname()">

        <div class="scoreboard-wrapper">
            <h1 class="scoreboard-titel">Scoreboard</h1>
            <p>Player 1 - </p><div id="outputa"></div>
            <p>Player 2 - </p><div id="outputb"></div>
            <button onclick="start()" id="startbtn">Start</button>
       </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Explain your answer

Comment: How can "call the function" be the solution for an error that was already reported *in that function*?

Comment: @JurriePiek check this answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working

```js
function storename() {
playereen = document.getElementById('p1').value;
playertwee = document.getElementById('p2').value;
console.log(playereen);
console.log(playertwee);
document.getElementById("outputa").innerHTML = playereen;
  }
  

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
storename();
});
```

```html
<div class="scoreboard-wrapper">
  <h1 class="scoreboard-titel">Scoreboard</h1>
  <p>Player 1 - </p><div id="outputa"></div>
  <p>Player 2 - </p><div id="outputb"></div>
  <button onclick="start()" id="startbtn">Start</button>
</div>

<button id="btn">Print</button>

<form id="form1">
        <p id="logintekst">Enter your names!</p>
        <input id="p1" class="form" type="text" placeholder="Player 1">
        <input id="p2" class="form" type="text" placeholder="Player 2">
        <a onclick="storename()"><div onclick="storename()" id="submit-btn">Submit</div></a>
    </form>
```

Comment: The question is not about an error on a line with `.value`, but one with `.innerHTML`

Comment: Maybe, but did you see the edit to the question? The OP shows the element is not absent.

Comment: "Seems to be working" is more of a comment; not an answer.

Comment: @trincot how could one answer on what's ok?

Comment: One would not answer. It is best to ask for clarification from the OP until it is clear why they still have a problem.

Comment: Its still not working i have the form and the scoreboard in seperate html files can that be a problem?

Comment: The JavaScript is working on one file. If you want to pass your data across files you could create a link dynamically like `my_file.html?player1=Player1&player2=Player2` it's a passing data by GET method

Comment: Actually, forms are used to be processed by server, not client side. If you want to do everything on client side you could make an SPA with help of Angular/ReactJS/Vue.JS etc. Or, you could make it by plain JavaScript.